# Software for simulation of motion of point masses

Tags: data-visualization, simulation

Is there a software in which I can use the governing equations of motion of point masses and the software shows me the trajectory of the point masses in space (Preferably a video of the motion).

**Software requirement**
Input: force/acceleration, initial velocity and position of the bodies
Output: Trajectory of the bodies in 3D

**Support**
OS support: Can be anything (Windows/Linux/OSX)
Free/Paid: Preferably free
Interface: GUI preferred (thought command line/textual inputs are tolerated)

*Note:* My focus here is on the trajectory drawing part, I am willing to code/script to any extent

Answer (score 1):

[SketchUp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SketchUp) (formerly: Google Sketchup) is a 3D modeling computer program for applications such as architectural, interior design, civil and mechanical engineering, film, and video game design.
[SketchyPhysics](https://code.google.com/p/sketchyphysics/) is a [physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOC7eSt1zK0) plugin for Google Sketchup.

Comment: I will check this out. Thanks @Davidenko. I will mark this as answer in a week's time. Expecting more answers